Tensor Notation with Basis in Differential Geometry
Let's say we have two smooth riemannian manifolds $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{S}$ and with coordinates $X^A$ on $\mathfrak{B}$ and $x^a$ on $\mathfrak{S}$, with $A,a \in \{1,2,3\}$
Let's now assume that $\mathfrak{B}$ has the basis $E_A$ and $\mathfrak{S}$ has the Basis $e_a$ are embedded in a space with a basis $E_a$. The tangential basis induced by the coordinates with it's basis on $\mathfrak{B}$ shall be denoted $H_A$ and on $\mathfrak{S}$ denoted $h_a$.
Let $\phi: \mathfrak{B} \rightarrow \mathfrak{S}$ be a bijective mapping between $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{S}$, in coordinates I commonly come accross the expression
for the tangent map in coordinates (einstein summation convention applies):
$$
\mathbf{F} = F^a_{\phantom{a}A} h_a \otimes H^A\quad \text{with} \quad F^a_{\phantom{a}A} = \frac{\partial \phi^a}{\partial X^A}
$$
which allows us to deduce formal relationships between basis transformations based on the contraction of covariant and contravariant basisvectors: $$
\mathbf{h} = \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{H} \\
\Leftrightarrow x^a h_a = (F^a_{\phantom{a}A} h_a \otimes H^A)\cdot X^B H_B \\
x^a h_a = F^a_{\phantom{a}A} X^B h_a \otimes (H^A\cdot  H_B) \\
x^a h_a = F^a_{\phantom{a}A} X^B h_a (\delta^A_B) \\
x^a h_a = F^a_{\phantom{a}A} X^A h_a \\
\implies x^a = F^a_{\phantom{a}A} X^A
$$
which I find very convenient for working with these objects.
I now want to apply this notation to the language of manifolds without an embedding space and just substituted each basis $h_a$ with it's correspondend $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$ or $h^a$ with $dx^a$, only working with the tangent map.
I now read $\mathbf{F}$ as $$
\mathbf{F} = F^a_{\phantom{a}A} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \otimes dX^A
$$
however i also see the following expression: $$
d\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{F}d\mathbf{X}
$$
which would imply $$
b_a dx^a = F_a^{\phantom{a}A} dx^a \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial X^A} ( a_B dX^B)
$$ in order to work with the Einstein summation convention. Obviously the two presented formulas for $\mathbf{F}$ are different, but i cannot clearly say why.
For anyone wondering, I came across this problem when trying to fix notation for elasticity.

A map $\phi$ from manifold $M$ to manifold $N$, induces a map $\phi_: T_m(M) \to T_{\phi(m)}(N)$ at each $m \in M$, and this map varies smoothly as a function of $m$. The pullback map, $\phi^$, induces a linear map from $T_{\phi(m)}^(N)$ to $T_m^(M)$. One can use $\phi^$ to pullback forms on $N$ to forms on $M$. Note also that $\phi_$ and $\phi^*$ are transposes of each other.

We have
$$\phi^*(b_a dx^a) = b_a F^a_{\phantom{a}B} dX^B.$$
We also have
$$ \phi^*(b_a dx^a) = a_B dX^B. $$
Comparing the last two formulas, we get
$$ a_B = b_a F^a_{\phantom{a}B},$$
which agrees with the Einstein summation convention and rules.

So, which basis in Cartan Notation would associated with a Tensor, whose components are $F^{a}_{\phantom{a}B}$?

The first formula for $\mathbf{F}$ that you wrote down was fine. I mean that $\mathbf{F} = F^a_{\phantom{a}A} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \otimes dX^A$. What you wrote down after "however I also see the following expression" is confusing to me.
Think of $\mathbf{F}$ as the linearization of the map $\phi$, so it induces a linear map from the tangent space at a point $p$ in the source manifold to the tangent space at the point $\phi(p)$ in the target manifold.

This notation is one I come across in differential calculus, when viewed from the intrinsic standpoint where the manifold isn't a embedding into an underlying space. All objects still exist, but the classical notion of a "tangent vector" does not. I commonly see as a basis the symbols $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$ as a standin for a covariant basis, whereas I see $dx^a$ as a standin for a contravariant basis. but if I naivly switch them out, I am confused why the map should have switched bases to make sense, or if I'm wrong in equating objects in extrinsic and intrinsic views.

Yes, please use more standard notation. It was difficult for me to remember what each symbol in your notation is (I write that, but some of my earlier articles definitely had this issue!). One way to think of standard notation is, if you use a basis for a vector space, then it makes sense to use the dual basis for the dual vector space. I don't think it is an issue of intrinsic vs extrinsic, in this case. Tangent vector fields and forms are all intrinsic notions, in that they do not depend on an embedding.

Note that if you have a linear map from a vector space $V$ to itself, then it has one index up and one index down, with respect to a chosen basis of $V$. With respect to the dual basis, its transpose is a map from $V^*$ to itself. This is compatible with Einstein's summation convention.
